# Twitter embed and widget slowing down my page

Tags: javascript

According to PageSpeed Insights Twitter is massively slowing my pageload speed
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qbxBA.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XqZVr.png)

im trying to load twitter only if the user scroll down to it otherwise there is no need to load it

```
<div class="testimonials__tweetbox">
                        <blockquote class="twitter-tweet"><p lang="en" dir="ltr">COMING SOON</p>&mdash; SuperMarioRistorante (@RistoranteSuper) <a href="https://twitter.com/RistoranteSuper/status/1284416990581530624?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw">July 18, 2020</a></blockquote> <script src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8" defer></script>
                    </div>
```

my lazyload

```
// LAZY LOADING Vanilla JS
var lottie = document.querySelectorAll('.twitter-tweet');
const appearOptions = {
    threshold: 0,
    rootMargin: "0px 0px -470px 0px"
  };

      var observer = new IntersectionObserver(function (entries, observer){
        entries.forEach(entry => {
            if (entry.isIntersecting) {
             var img = entry.target;
                observer.unobserve(entry.target);
                console.log(entry)
              }
        });
      },
      appearOptions);
      lottie.forEach(img => {
        observer.observe(img);
      });
// End of LAZY LOADING Vanilla JS
```

why on page refresh the twitter widget still gets loaded ?

Comment: Not my solution, but I came across these when faced with the same problem. Possibly they can be of help to you or others:

Static Tweet Render with Next.js:
https://static-tweet.vercel.app/

React library built on the previous solution:
https://github.com/transitive-bullshit/react-static-tweets